# Django How to make conditional forms, query, and character replacement

Tags: javascript, django, forms, unicode

I am working on a language app that will

1. generate form to take user input > search db > if it exists in db, return the input word and the translated word
2. if input does not exist, prompt user if they want to add new word to dictionary > new form will have 2 text areas one for the word in english and the other for the word in other language > return (display) user inputs to confirm if entered correctly > if correct save to db
3. the text area used in the input for the word in other language must be able to handle unicode characters. i can do this part in html javascript as seen below.... I have basic understanding of django but how can I combine everything (particularly the char replacement) it into a seamless django app?

   ```
   <script>
    function replaceStuff(aObj){
    aObj.innerHTML = aObj.innerHTML.replace('.O','Ọ')
    aObj.innerHTML = aObj.innerHTML.replace('.o','ọ');
    aObj.innerHTML = aObj.innerHTML.replace('.E','Ẹ');
    aObj.innerHTML = aObj.innerHTML.replace('.e','ẹ');
   }

   function printStuff(aObj){
       document.getElementById("strDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tArea").innerHTML;
   }
   </script>

   </head>
   <textarea id="tArea" onkeyup="replaceStuff(this);"></textarea> 
   <br />
   <button id="button" onclick="printStuff(this);">Print Stuff</button>
   <br /><br /><br /><br />
   <div id="strDiv" />

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: You say the text area must be able to *handle* Unicode, but your code suggests that you are actually concerned about how the users *produce* Unicode characters (ie. the input method). This is something you should leave to the user – have them install an alternative keyboard layout to type the characters of the language in question, or something like that. Replacing ".e" with "ẹ" might be annoying – what if a user actually wants to input ".e" for some reason?

Comment: Your are right the issue is really how the users can produce unicode characters to save to db through simple text input form. I'd rather not give the users more work to do by having everyone map their own keyboards; but instead use input syntax that is universal